# Android resize file till certain size

Tags: android, file

I have a file (an image from picked gallery or camera capture intent). This image can have different weight (from 1 MB till 10 MB). Is it possible to compress any file image till a certain weight ?? Let's say for example to set a limit of 1 MB ?

Comment: where and what should do the resizing?

Comment: sorry i meant to compress , instead of resizing

Comment: no worries. though i am still wondering that you are the first one picking that username! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compress it by a factor proportional to initial size versus target size (e.g. 10MB -> 1MB factor 10%, 4MB-> 1MB 25%), but the correlation between size and compression ratio is looser than that between image pixel dimensions and size.

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(originalImagePath));
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetImagePath);
original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, ratio, out);
```

If your images contain a lot of solid colors, then a 10% compression might not be visible too much, but if your images rely on a lot of gradient transitions you will notice the decress in image quality caused by compression.